# MongoDb about 2 million entries in about 100 collections

Tags: mongodb, collections

I want to move customer surveys for different products and survey types into mongodb.

A product can have multiple survey types.

The existing data consists of about 2 million surveys and growing.

There will be a need of querying the data for stats and reports and the structure of the surveys and their questions can change over time. Which means that the documents wont always be the same.

What will suite the best:

- One big collection with product_id and type overhead within one db
- Multiple collections per product and type within one db
- Or a mix of multiple dbs and collections for product and type

I read about advantages and disadvantages and also that every case has its own solution that suits the usage and purpose.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what applies the best for my case.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you will access you data, it is by customer, survey or product?.

You can make a product collection and put the surveys as an array of subdocuments or you can make a customer collection and do the same thing.

It is not something we can help you with here without knowing the details of the business requirement.

Just keep in mind, MongoDB is schemaless and how you will design your documents and collections depends on how you will access your data.

Comment: Ok, the access will be per product and it's survey type. Cross queries wont be necessary most of the time. I was considering a collection per product and type. Basically about 30 products, each about 3 types makes 90 collections. When there is a new survey type I will create another collection for it. Would that make sense?

Comment: Why not making one collection of products, and make inside that collection an array of surveys subdocuments?. Another think: Max Size of MongoDB documents is 16Mb. Just something to keep in mind.